# Android shell svc data enable working on one phone and not on another one

Tags: android, shell, adb

I'm trying to figure out why an adb shell command is working on one phone and not on a different one.
This is running on a Samsung Galaxy 10

**C:\Users\ivan>adb shell**

**beyond0:/ $ svc data disable**

**beyond0:/ $ svc data enable**

**beyond0:/ $ exit**

No errors and commands are correctly executed.

On a Samsung Galaxy J3 this is what happens:

**C:\Users\ivan>adb shell**

**shell@j3xnlte:/ $ svc data disable**

**sh: resetreason: can't execute: Permission denied**

**Killed**

The error tells me a permissions problem... but both phones are not rooted. Commands are executed from the same pc.

Comment: Most likely they are running with different Android versions. BTW: Android non-development questions are off-topic here. Such questions should better be posted on  https://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: You are correct. Permission changed between those versions. Tahnk you.